# Levy's theorem that the characteristic function determines the distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Levy's formula that gives $F(b) - F(a)$ in terms of a complicated integral formula involving the characteristic function looks like magic. My question is therefore the following: is there some natural setting that this formula falls out from? Since the characteristic function is just a Fourier transform is there a natural characterization of it in terms of Fourier theory and inner-products?

Comment: I think the theorem can be understood as kind of Fourier Inversion under a nice situation, e.g. $F$ has a density and the characteristic function $\phi$ is integrable. Further complication is to make sure the case $\phi$ is not integrable or $F$ does not have a density.